# Amity Typescript SDK is not working properly

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am working on a project and when ever i am trying to initiate a client it keeps on giving me an error that "web socket not initialised"

```
import { Client, API_REGIONS } from '@amityco/ts-sdk';

let amity = async () => {
  try {
    const sessionHandler: Amity.SessionHandler = {
      sessionWillRenewAccessToken(renewal: Amity.AccessTokenRenewal) {
        renewal.renew();
      }
    }

    const client: Amity.Client = Client.createClient("API Key", API_REGIONS.EU);
    console.log("client login",sessionHandler)
    let isConnected = `await client.mqtt.connect({ userId: "umar", sessionHandler })`
    console.log(isConnected)
    // console.log(client)
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
export default amity
```

On documentation I had scene that `await client.mqtt.connect({ userId: "umar", sessionHandler })` is
`await client.login({ userId: "umar", sessionHandler })`
but when I am using this it says "login" is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The amity SDK is purely used for front end that's why you are not able to access the primary functions.
Primarily it uses session handler to play with web sockets, and we know that web sockets are the instincts of web browsers not the programming language. That's why you always get session handler always "undefined" if used on backend.
The amity support says if you want to use the functionality of SDK either implement it on front-end or use the api provided by the amity team.
Here is the link of Amity Api's
"https://api-docs.amity.co/"
Hope so you will enjoy the coding.
Quantum coder